# Threading arguments from lists of different size

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, mapthread

How to construct the function combinationsF ?

```
list1 = {x, y}
list2 = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
combinationsF[list1, list2]
(*should give {F[x,a] F[y,b],F[x,c] F[y,d],F[x,e] F[y,f]}*)
```

I've tried Thread, MapThread, Apply and combinations but I'm missing something

Comment: `{list1, list2} // (Tuples /* Map[MapThread[F]] /* Catenate)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Inner[F, list1, #, Sequence] & /@ list2
```

> {F[x, a], F[y, b], F[x, c], F[y, d], F[x, e], F[y, f]}

Compare with the following that can be flattened later, if required.

```
Inner[F, list1, #, List] & /@ list2
```

> {{F[x, a], F[y, b]}, {F[x, c], F[y, d]}, {F[x, e], F[y, f]}}

Comment: (+1) For 12.1+ we can make it even easier: `Inner[ReverseApplied[F], list2, list1, Sequence]`

Comment: Thank you! You've got a very elegant and short answer. Specially with the variation of Ben Izd. About answers with Threaded, I didn't download v13.1 yet (sorry!)

Comment: Not as neat as the Ben Izd variation, but `Inner[F[#2,#1]&, list2, list1,Sequence]` maybe also deserves a mention?

Answer (score 14):

This can be achieved with the new function `Threaded` (introduced in V13.1):

```
SetAttributes[f1, Listable]
f1[Threaded[list1], list2]
Flatten[%]
```

> {{f[x, a], f[y, b]}, {f[x, c], f[y, d]}, {f[x, e], f[y, f]}}

> {f[x, a], f[y, b], f[x, c], f[y, d], f[x, e], f[y, f]}

If you don't want to mess with the attributes of the function itself you can use `Function`:

```
Flatten[Function[{x, y}, f2[x, y], Listable][Threaded[list1], list2]]
```

> {f2[x, a], f2[y, b], f2[x, c], f2[y, d], f2[x, e], f2[y, f]}

Answer (score 9):

```
Table[
  Sequence @@ MapThread[F,{list1, j}],
  {j, list2}
]
```

> {F[x, a], F[y, b], F[x, c], F[y, d], F[x, e], F[y, f]}

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this using `Table`:

```
F @@@ (Join @@ Table[Transpose@{list1, list2[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[list2]}])

(*{F[x, a], F[y, b], F[x, c], F[y, d], F[x, e], F[y, f]}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
la = {x, y};

lb = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}};
```

```
F @@@ Catenate @ Map[Transpose[{la, #}] &, lb]
```

> {F[x, a], F[y, b], F[x, c], F[y, d], F[x, e], F[y, f]}